# /proc/PID files' format

Tags: linux, process

I want to retrieve some process info from `/proc` directory and my question is the following: is there a standart format for files in `/proc/PID`?
For example, there is this `proc/PID/status` file with `Name:'\t'ProcName` in its first line. Can I meet this file elsewhere with a whitespace instead of `\t` or smth like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, the documentation on `/proc` in Linux is provided in the Linux sources, in [`Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt). That should be the first place you look into if going to work with procfs. Sadly, AFAICS it doesn't mention the exact record format.

The second place to look is `procps` sources (that is, the package which provides `ps` tool). There you can find:

```
colon = strchr(S, ':');
if(unlikely(!colon)) break;
if(unlikely(colon[1]!='\t')) break;
```

which means that `ps` relies on the `:\t` being there. Therefore, you can assume that all current Linux kernels use this format. Moreover, I doubt that minor changes (like replacing the `\t` with something else) would be considered important enough to break compatibility with the old versions of `ps` tool.

That said, you can usually be more liberal in what you accept. Considering the specific contents of that file, you can assume the colon being field separator, and strip any whitespace following it. If you are using shell script, the regular field separation should suffice.

Lastly, I'd like to make a few points:

1. The `status` file is supposed to be *human-readable*. Therefore, programs are usually better reading the `stat` file instead which is designed to be machine-oriented.
2. I am considering Linux here only (based on tags). Different systems may have a bit different `/proc` format.
3. If you are writing a C program (the *shell* tag was added by an editor), you should consider using the `libprocps` library which comes with `procps` instead of reading the files by hand. That way, you avoid re-inventing the wheel and relying on a specific format directly.

Comment: "stat" is really much better, thanks. Sadly, the point of my work is to re-invent the wheel:)